# Get rows that are less than 10 years old from the beginning of the year

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I'm using this code `date > timestampadd(year, -10, NOW())` to return data that is less than 10 years old.

I need **January 1, 2007** instead of **July 28, 2007** (10 years ago from NOW())

Was hoping something like this `date > timestampadd(year, -10, YEAR(NOW()))` would work, but it doesn't.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create any date you need using `STR_TO_DATE()`:

`YEAR(now)` will give you the year.

**[Sql DEMO](http://rextester.com/NVS71309)**

Then just build it like:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(concat(YEAR(now()),  '/01/01'), "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: Why over-complicate it when `date_trunc()` does exactly that?

Comment: I'd say it's not generic enough, but that's just me. In this state, you still have manual entry of having to put the /01/01. With date_trunc, you can specify as specific as you want to get and then everything else defaults to 0 or 1.

Comment: If you needed the 15th of the month, then you wouldn't need to use date_trunc. You could just use `datediff()` because you don't need to cut off part of the date.

Comment: Not saying it's wrong, because it works. I'm just trying to find the use instead of built-in functions.

Comment: I noticed you used a `SELECT`, can I use that same code in a `WHERE` clause?

If `date` is the column i'm filtering by

Comment: Yes, you can Donvan, is just for debug propose so you can see the result of the function.

Comment: Indeed. I just realized that.

Comment: Hooray for delete